# Why is the p:cellEditor not updating correctly?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uicomponents

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<h:panelGrid>   
    <p:dataTable id="datatableId" var="obj" value="#{myBean.dataList}" editable="true" editMode="cell"  rowKey="#{obj.id}" rowIndexVar="rowindex">

        <!-- some other columns -->

        <p:column>      
            <p:cellEditor id="targetEditorId" disabled="#{myBean.disabled}">
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{obj.foo}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputNumber value="#{obj.foo}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column> 
                            
        <p:column>  
            <p:commandLink value="edit" process="@this" action="#{myBean.linkAction}" update="datatableId:#{rowindex}:targetEditorId">          
        </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Boolean value disabled is responsible for the value of the cellEditor attribute "disabled":

```
private boolean disabled;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    setDisabled(true);
}

// getter
// setter
```

CommandLink action:

```
public void linkAction() {
    setDisabled(false);
}
```

So, the problem is that when i click on the commandLink i expect that the cell will be editable, but it doesn't happen. Howewer, if i initially set attribute disabled="#{!myBean.disabled}" - it works (initially the cell is editable. when i click the link - becomes unavailable for editing), but the task requires the opposite.
P.S. i know about <p:rowEditor> , but the task involves the use of commandLink to cell-editing

Comment: @JasperdeVries I agree, but this does not solve the problem

Comment: If the component is initialized with `disabled="true"`, it will not be present in the JSF tree, so AJAX can't update it, see https://coderanch.com/t/595646/java/Change-disabled-attribute-client-side
If you could explain why you have to use commandLink, maybe we can help you?